# Cross domain iframe src changes

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, oracle-adf, business-process-management

I have an application which contains an iframe. I can modify the contents of the iframe, but not the whole page itself, e.g.:

```
<html><head></head>
<body> 
    <iframe>
        <!-- my code -->
    </iframe>
</body></html>
```

I have a requirement in which I need to change contents of the iframe to a different page (possibly on a different domain) and go back. Currently I do it like this:
The first page (it is inside the iframe executionPanelApplications):

```
<html> 
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function replaceIFrameUrl() {
    var doSubmit = "<c:out value='${param.doSubmit}'/>";
    if (doSubmit == 1) {
        document.forms['testForm'].submit();
    }
    else {
        var adfUrl = "<fuego:fieldValue att='instJs.adfUrl' onlyValue='true'/>";
        var bpmSrc = parent.document.getElementById('executionPanelApplications').src;
        var bpmSrcParams = bpmSrc.split('&');
        var activityId = (bpmSrcParams[1].split('='))[1]; 
        var url = adfUrl +"&actionType=0&activityId="+activityId;
        parent.document.getElementById('executionPanelApplications').src = url;
    }
};

</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="replaceIFrameUrl();">
    <form method="post" id="testForm" name="testForm" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

The second page (it should be inside the iframe executionPanelApplications as well):

```
 <script>
   function leave(e) {
      var iframe = parent.parent.document.getElementById("executionPanelApplications");
      iframe.src = url;
   };
 </script>
```

If both sites are in localhost it works like a charm. Unfortunatelly if they are in different domains - the second page is opened in a new window. Tested in ie 8. As i said - i can't change the contents of the page that contains the iframe. I can only work from inside the iframe. I need this to work only in ie.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is why you should avoid the ugly iFrame. It's a known limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use iframes, because there are different security restrictions (cross domain communication)

But I think, this one can help you: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: Well as i said I can't do much about it - the first page is in an iframe. The technology behind all this is Oracle BPM 10g. I want to replace the page supplied by the BPM application with a different web interface, relatively seamless.